# How could I able to open whole website into particuler div?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website where there is a requirement to open another website into particular div. I had try below mentioned code but I am not able to get output with proper appearance.

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height:300px; width:100%" >
      <?php echo $url ?>
</div>
```

I have to use only div. no I-frame nothing else. belowmention code i am use. and class name of this function is Scraper

```
  function getPagePost($url, $data = array(), $proxy='', $userpass='', $header = array()) {
        $ch = curl_init();

        if(!empty($header)){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
        }


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if($this->useCookie)
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->ckfile);         
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

        if(!empty($proxy))
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

        if(!empty($userpass))
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $userpass);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if($result === false) {
            $result = curl_error($ch);
        }   

        curl_close($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

============================================

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])){

require_once 'scraper.php';
$scraper = new Scraper(); 
$url = $scraper->getPagePost($_POST['url']);
?>  

     <div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height:300px; width:100%" >
          <?php echo $url; ?>
     </div>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any security concerns ?

Comment: no. this is because of in SRS it mentioned

Comment: I cant provide a good answer to you because the method you suggested is really worst. Normally clients are not aware of many things. A better idea would be make them understand why this method is worst and  not recommended. Just curious, What types of web sites you are loading ? What is the top level requirement ?

Answer (score 4):

You need an `iframe` to do that like

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height:300px; width:100%" >
    <iframe src="<?php echo $url;?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

But some of the sites like `Gmail` will not support this Because All of Google's websites have a code in there header, "x-frame-option: sameorigin" that causes it to only run on google websites. They cannot open in iframes

Comment: as per your code I am not able to open it and getting forbidden error. and i do not down vote your comment

Comment: Just try the url in new browser in an new tab and see it is working or not ...Then you can try it in iframe and I already told that not all the sites will open on iframes even

Answer (score 1):

I think using an `include` is what you're looking for, although your question isn't quite clear.  You should have:

```
<div style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height:300px; width:100%" >
  <?php include $url ?>
</div>
```

`$url` should be the path to the other "website" you need to put into your div.  If the other "website" is a complete other website then this will work but some portions might not work depending on what is on the other website.  Any http headers or some other things may not work and your resulting html code will not be valid, but it will display something resembling the original website.

I will stress that this is not a technically correct answer since the only technically correct and valid way to show another full website on another one is by using an i-frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the object embed method instead of an iframe. http://jsfiddle.net/gDUUv/1/

E.g.:

```
<object data="<?php echo $url ?>" width="600" height="400">
    <embed src="<?php echo $url ?>" width="600" height="400"> </embed>
</object>
```